# Xalan XSLT multiple output files?

Tags: xml, xslt, xalan

I'd just like to know, is it possible to output the processing of a single input XML file to multiple other files using Xalan?

I don't necessarily HAVE to do it that way, I know I can use other tools to do it (like Saxon), and/or I could process different files to obtain different outputs. I'd just like to know the options I have to do exactly what I'm asking for with the very tools I'm planning on using. Any reason why I shouldn't use that tool to do this task is also welcome.

The context is kinda simple, I'm trying to transform an XML file that represents the structure of a multipage, multilanguage website. The (current and potentially future) structure of the file is something like

```
    <pages>
      <page>
        <language name="xyz">
          <!-- More interesting stuff -->
        </language>
      </page>
    </pages>
```

Potentially, a page will contain multiple languages, but it doesn't have to be so.

Comment: I was going to tell you to use the `<xsl:document>` element, then I remembered that a while ago I ended up switching from Xalan to Saxon, and I don't think Xalan supports this element. Saxon and libxslt2 do, though, but I doubt it's much use to you.

Comment: I don't really mind if the answer to the question is "Unless you want your soul to burn in hell for using such black magic, you won't be able to use it." I'm already looking at the free Saxon version, I think it might be easier to deal with than Xalan. Going to research libxslt2, though.

Comment: It all depends on your setup. libxslt has bindings for Perl, Python and Ruby, for example. If you're doing servlets or JSP, you're maybe better off with Saxon. I've only used XSLT in scripts that I run locally, in which case libxslt is handy as it comes with the xsltproc command line tool.

Comment: Actually I might very well switch to Saxon eventually. It's a little more practical to have builtin 2.0 functions than a metric hellton of extensions, in my humble misguided opinion, mainly because I can "depend" on the specs to expect some of the things to work in XYZ way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using [Xalan-J](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/) or [Xalan-C](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-c/)? If you are using Xalan-J, the [Redirect](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensionslib.html#redirect) extension should do the trick.

Comment: Yeah, well, it seems like it is the proper solution for what I'm seeking to do, but I still encounter problems with it, redirect:write spits out errors and dies miserably. I'll have to look at other alternatives, I guess.

Comment: My bad, somehow, Xalan didn't like how I did some of the stuff, but I can't say I know how I actually fixed the thing. Which is a little unsettling.